# Error connecting to VM service for Flutter DevTools

Tags: flutter

The message I get is:

```
Unable to connect to VM service at http://127.0.0.1:53932/pq_PklwHCMK=/:
getDartDevelopmentServiceVersio: (-32601)
Method not found,
getDartDevelopmentServiceVersio: (-32601)
Method not found
```

**What I have tried:**

- Restarting computer
- Restarting VScode
- Restarting Emulator
- Wiping AVD data
- Coldboot AVD
- Tried opening devtools in browser, same message
- Checked flutter doctor for any issues (none)

This was working for years until now, and I do see that in VScode that Dar and Flutter for VScode was updated 1 hour ago to 3.19.0 so I downgraded but I still get this same issue.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/773

Comment: @fartem link, This did not work fo me

Comment: @WesleyBarnes check https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2648

Comment: Thanks! @TortillaPack working again, downgraded one and launched in terminal , good to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
  void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

to

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and write in terminal

```
flutter pub global activate devtools 0.9.6+3
```

and

```
dart pub global activate devtools 0.9.6+3
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue should have been fixed since devtools version `0.9.7+2` as mentioned on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2648#issuecomment-770566765). If you're still using an older version and encounters this issue, I recommend updating to the latest version of devtools.